# Laravel: Routes with parameters

Tags: laravel-5.4

I have following case:

```
Route::get('/kids_report_card/{id?}/{param?}', 'KidsReportCardController@index');
```

And in view file I have:

```
{{ url('kids_report_card/4') }}
```

In some other view file I have:

```
{{ url('kids_report_card/name') }} (where name is string here-some parameter)
```

Now the situation is:
For `{{ url('kids_report_card/4') }}` ,`Route::get('/kids_report_card/{id?}/{param?}', 'KidsReportCardController@index');` works fine.

For `{{ url('kids_report_card/name') }}`,`Route::get('/kids_report_card/{id?}/{param?}', 'KidsReportCardController@index');` doesn't work fine as in `url` we have `name` parameter while in `Route` we have first parameter as `id`(integer value). so is there any dynamic solution that srting parameter must go to second parameter in Route??

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of parameters in the url like this:

```
{{ url('kids_report_card', ['name' => 'name_value']) }}
```

Reference: [URL's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#urls)

Comment: ok, by array we can give many parameters as we want, but my question belongs to some other problem